# how to fix "undefined reference to 'Shape::Shape()' - Build failed 3 error(s) in C++"

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm learning C++ OO Design and I came across the following problem where I have to use abstract classes and inheritance.

I'm working in a problem where I have to use an abstract class called `Shape` that should contain a virtual function named `get_area()` which returns a `double`.

- Class `Circle` inherits `Shape` class and contains constructor & member functions:

  - `Circle(double radius)`
  - `double get_radius()`
  - `void set_radius(double radius)`
  - `double get_area()`
- Class `Square` inherits the `Shape` class and contains:

  - `Square(double width)`
  - `double get_width()`
  - `void set_width(double width)`
  - `double get_area()`
- Class `Rectangle` inherits `Square` class and contains:

  - `Rectangle(double width, double height)`
  - `double get_height()`
  - `void set_height(double width)`
  - `double get_area()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public:
        Shape();
        virtual double get_area() const = 0;
};

// Circle sub-class
class Circle : public Shape {
    private:
        double r;
    public:
        Circle(double radius) : Shape() {
            r = radius;
        }
        void set_radius(double radius) {
            r = radius;
        }
        double get_radius() {
            return r;
        }

        virtual double get_area() const {
            return 3.14159 * pow(r, 2);
        }
};

// Square sub-class
class Square : public Shape {
    protected:
        double w;
    public:
        Square(double width) : Shape() {
            w = width;
        }

        void set_width(double width) {
            w = width;
        }

        double get_width() const {
            return w;
        }

        virtual double get_area() const {
            return w * w;
        }
};

/*
// Rectangle sub-class
class Rectangle : public Shape, public Square {
    private:
        double h, w;
    public:
        Rectangle(double width, double height) : Shape(){
            h = height;
            w = width;
        }

        void set_heigth(double height) {
            h = height;
        }

        void set_width(double width) {
            w = width;
        }

        double get_height() const {
            return h;
        }

        double get_width() const {
            return w;
        }

        virtual double get_area() const {
            return h * w;
        }
};

*/

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    Circle c(5.5);
    cout << "\t" << c.get_radius() << endl;

    //Rectangle r(4.2, 2.5);
    //cout << "\t" << r.get_width() << " " << r.get_height() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is actually doing:

> undefined reference to 'Shape::Shape()

The `Rectangle` class also throws an error, that is why it is commented

What should do: I should be able to create an object from any of this classes, named `Circle c`, and get the area by inputting the radius.

Comment: Where is the definition of `Shape::Shape`? I can only see a declaration of it.

Comment: You should not be using multiple inheritance on `Rectangle`, it already inherits `Shape` from `Square` so there is no need to specify `Shape` a second time. Also, a square is a specialized type of rectangle, but a rectangle is not a square, so your `Square` class should derive from `Rectangle`, not the other way around. The `Square` constructor can call the `Rectangle` constructor passing the `width` as the `height`, and then you can get rid of all the members from `Square`

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to your inheritance, abstract classes, or OO design. The problem is, you've declared `Shape::Shape`, i.e. the constructor, but there is no definition. So the linker is complaining that it can't find the code for the constructor.

Try just deleting `Shape`'s constructor, you don't need it from the look of things.

Comment: Or provide it with an inlined implementation: `class Shape { public: Shape() {} ... };`

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you do that, the value for `std::is_trivial<T>::value` will be different. Better to just delete or use ` = default;`.